# Java Interface with diagonal cross line

Tags: interface

In my maven project in eclipse some of the imported interfaces has a diagonal cross line on its icon.

Why there is that diagonal cross line on the interface icon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

This is because the interface is marked as *deprecated* (with the @Deprecated annotation).
This is a sign to not use the interface anymore, because it might be deleted in newer versions of the lib.

Comment: If you got a right answer to any question, please do not forget to accept it, so other users can see that they are done.